# How Can I turn off the grain effect in Silent Hill 3 (PC version)?

Tags: silent-hill-series, silent-hill-3

The question is simple. I tried the sh3 config utility, searched on google and sh wiki but no luck? Do you have any idea?

Please note that I'm playing the original, not the HD version.

Comment: what platform are you playing it on?

Comment: I'm playing the PC version. I edited my question.

Comment: "In Silent Hill 3 you have the option to turn the noise filter off which does make it look better, and makes the graphical update clearer, but that may take away from the atmosphere a little bit." - thats all i could find... Grain Effect = Noise Filter. double check settings.

Comment: I checked options like 4 times. Now I checked them again but still no luck. Maybe I have to finish it first to be able to turn it off like in Silent Hill 2?

Comment: Can you provide a link for your quote?

Comment: http://www.primaryignition.com/2012/03/21/first-impressions-silent-hill-hd-collection/
I wouldn't call it conclusive as it was for HD and PS3...

Comment: Yeah, that is another version sadly.

Comment: "The grain effect also adds an element of fear to the game but I chose to turn it off, as it seems to detract from the breathtaking visuals." http://www.christcenteredgamer.com/index.php/reviews/18-computer/4636-silent-hill-3-pc is for the correct version and says you can turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the game's Options menu, you need to go to the Extra Options Menu where you can turn the noise/grain filter off. On the PS2, you did this with the L1 button as described [here](http://guides.ign.com/guides/482701/page_2.html). On PC, I'm not sure what button it is, but since the PS2 uses L1 and R1 to turn and the PC version uses Q and E to turn, **I would try hitting the Q or E buttons from the Options menu to see if you can access the Extra Options.**